# Help Solving Recurrence Relation: $a_n = n^3a_{n-1} + (n!)^3$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm trying to find an explicit formula for the following recurrence relation:

> $a_0 = 1$,  $\forall n \ge 1: a_n = n^3a_{n-1} + (n!)^3$

So far though, my attempts have been unsuccessful.

---

**My Attempt**

Let $A(x) = a_n\frac{x^n}{(n!)^3}$. Multiply by $\frac{x^n}{(n!)^3}$ and sum over $n$ to get:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n\frac{x^n}{(n!)^3}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{n-1}\frac{x^n}{(n-1!)^3}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^n}$$

This can be simplified to:

$$
A(x) - a_0 = xA(x) + \frac{1}{1-x} \\
\implies A(x) = \frac{2-x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Using partial fraction decomposition you recover that $A(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)} + \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$, which means that $$A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+1)x^n} \\
\implies A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+2)x^n}$$

Then, to put $A(x)$ back into the form that we defined it in in the beginning, we have:
$$A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+2)(n!)^3\frac{x^n}{(n!)^3}} \\
\implies a_n = (n+2)(n!)^3$$

---

I'm wonderring if anyone can provide some insight into where I could have gone wrong. Is the original definition of $A(x)$ valid, or must I stick to either an ordinary / exponential generating function? If so, how could I clear the variable terms in the recurrence?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \dfrac x {1 - x} \ne \dfrac 1 {1 - x}$$

Comment: Wow, I'm rather embarrassed that I let that slip by. It's always the small things I suppose.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: Divide by $(n!)^3$ and define $\displaystyle b_n=\frac{a_n}{(n!)^3}$ to get
$$
b_n =b_{n-1}+1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to find these sequences (so simple it is almost cheating!) is to generate the first few terms and search for the resulting sequence in the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](https://oeis.org/).  In this case you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
a_0 &= 1, \\[6pt]
a_1 &= 1^3 a_0 + (1!)^3 = 1^3 \cdot 1 + 1^3 = 2, \\[6pt]
a_2 &= 2^3 a_1 + (2!)^3 = 2^3 \cdot 2 + 2^3 = 24, \\[6pt]
a_3 &= 3^3 a_2 + (3!)^3 = 3^3 \cdot 24 + 6^3 = 864, \\[6pt]
a_4 &= 4^3 a_3 + (4!)^3 = 4^3 \cdot 864 + 24^3 = 69120, \\[6pt]
&\quad \vdots \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Searching the terms `1, 2, 24, 864, 69120` on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) leads to a single hit for the integer sequence [A172492](https://oeis.org/A172492), which has the form:

$$a_n = (n!)^2 \cdot (n+1)! \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } n = 0,1,2,3,....$$

---

**Inductive proof:** It is now possible to prove that this form is correct using [proof by weak induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).  For the base case $n=0$ we have:

$$a_0 = (0!)^2 \cdot (0+1)! = 1^2 \cdot 1! = 1 \cdot 1 = 1.$$

For the inductive step we assume that $a_k = (k!)^2 \cdot (k+1)!$ and we then have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
a_{k+1} 
&= (k+1)^3 a_k + (k+1)!^3 \\[6pt]
&= (k+1)^3 \cdot (k!)^2 \cdot (k+1)! + (k+1)!^3 \\[6pt]
&= (k+1) \cdot (k+1)!^2 \cdot (k+1)! + (k+1)!^3 \\[6pt]
&= (k+1) \cdot (k+1)!^3 + (k+1)!^3 \\[6pt]
&= [(k+1) + 1] \cdot (k+1)!^3 \\[6pt]
&= (k+2) \cdot (k+1)!^3 \\[6pt]
&= (k+1)!^2 \cdot (k+2)!. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Since the base case is correct, and the inductive step is proved, this proves that the sequence you are dealing with is the integer sequence [A172492](https://oeis.org/A172492), with explicit form given above.